# Call is not going from my ios app to Skype

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am new for Ios app in my project  i have  added the facility for user make call from ios app to skype

for this  i have installed skype in my device and when i made call call from my app call not going

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
NSString * userNameString = @"sarithasai";

NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@";skype://%@?call", userNameString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Comment: Is the `;` in front of `skype` intentional?

Comment: Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Dn745885.aspx ?

Comment: yes i have seen i ahve alredy installed skype in my device

Comment: Which iOS version are you trying? Remember that starting with iOS 9, you have to register the URL scheme's you're trying to access.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Skype URI tutorial: iOS apps by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Dn745885.aspx) your schema is wrong. You should probably use the following instead:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:%@?call", userNameString];
```

Note that you should check wether or not Skype is installed beforehand which is mentioned in the linked article as well.

To start a chat use the schema

```
skype:user?chat
```

To start a video call use

```
skype:user?call&video=true
```

Comment: so for video calls and chat which urI's are we have to use?

Comment: @Anil Take a look at further URI specifications by Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx -> skype:user?chat and skype:user?call&video=true

Comment: yes when i clicked "call ended" button in skype app it must redirected to my app how shoud redirect?

Comment: @Anil That has nothing to do with the original question and is a unique and different topic, accept my answer on this question since it answers your current question. Then ask a second question on the SO network.

Comment: Only thing I know is that it **was** not possible, don't know if that is still the case

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
   BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];

  if(installed)
  {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:%@?call", userNameString]]];
  }
  else
  {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
  }
```

for more detail follow [here](http://www.skype.com/en/developer/).

Comment: so for video calls and chat which urI's are we have to use?

Comment: yes when i clicked "call ended" button in skype app it must redirected to my app how shoud redirect?